# How to programmatically download all contents of webpage, not only the source code in Java

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, css

I know how to download a webpage's source in java. But a webpage also contains image url, CSS and JS script url which need to be downloaded later like:

```
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="htmlatex.css">
<img src=p10012.gif>
```

If I only download the source of a webpage, rendering it in offline mode will need to download this `htmlatex.css` and `p10012.gif` result in missing contents in offline mode. My objective is to download all contents of webpage programmatically and provide it as assets of an android app. HOw can I do that in java.

Note: please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: So you want to download somebody's web site and use it as material for your own app. This is at risk of infringing copyright, at the very least.

Comment: NO! In my case, no such copyright issue! For example - this is one of the webpage: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/100/10012.html and I want to download all contents by designing a robot program and provide in my app. I swear its permissible :)

Comment: You will have to parse the HTML to find URLs for external resources. [Use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+parse+html).

Comment: I know I have to do such thing if I want to do it manually. But do you know if there exists any library for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library to do it as its pretty good HTML parse. You can parse HTML and than iterate over resources to download them. I am not sure but there should be an example on the same topic you asked.